# Knockout pureComputed Not Working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having a ridiculous time trying to handle addresses using Knockout. My structure is something like:

```
    viewModel.buildings()[0].Address()...
```

Where Address is:

```
    var Address = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.cAddr1 = ko.observable("");
        self.cCity = ko.observable("");
        ...
        self.cDisplay = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return self.cAddr1() + '<br>' + self.cCity() + ...;
        }
        self.AddressActions = new AddressActions();
    }
```

Everything seems to work ok. Each building has an address and the observables are updated properly. The cDisplay also works correctly.

I am wanting to add another computed/observable/whatever that will call a function that is part of AddressActions when the address changes. I tried this, but the console.log never even gets hit which doesn't make any sense to me:

```
    var Address = function () {
        // Same as above...
        ...
        self.triggerAddressVerify = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            console.log('here');
            self.cAddr1(); self.cAddr2(); self.cCity(); self.cState(); self.cZip();
            self.AddressActions.VerifyAddress(self);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

**Result**
So I'm still new to knockout.js (obviously) but it works a little bit differently than I thought. I basically used the accepted answer but wrapped everything into a pureComputed. Here's what I ended up adding:

```
    var Address = function () {
        ...
        self.addressChangeEvent = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return self.cAddr1() + self.cAddr2() + self.cCity() self.cState() + self.cZip();
        }
        self.addressChangeEvent.subscribe(function () {
            self.AddressActions.VerifyAddress(self);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A pureComputed only gets executed if it has subscribers listening to it. That can mean either another computed that uses it, or a binding in your html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you're looking for `subscribe` rather than `computed`

```
self.cAddr1.subscribe(function(){
    self.AddressActions.VerifyAddress(self);
});
```

you can add a subscription for each variable you need an event for

Answer (score 1):

The Knockout documentation for pure computed specifically says to not use it when you intend to perform some action ([side effects](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html#when-not-to-use-a-pure-computed-observable)).

> You should not use the pure feature for a computed observable that is meant to perform an action when its dependencies change.

You can use a regular computed instead.

```
self.triggerAddressVerify = ko.computed(function () {
    console.log('here');
    self.cAddr1(); self.cAddr2(); self.cCity(); self.cState(); self.cZip();
    self.AddressActions.VerifyAddress(self);
});
```

But note that this will run once initially as well as on future changes. If you only want to perform an action on future changes, your approach of subscribing to a pure computed is better.